# Nginx. Override header in cached object, is it possible?

Tags: nginx, cache

My team uses nginx with [cache](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-caching-guide/). The problem is that the application in upstream sends some headers that we would like to override *in the cached object*. One can see the headers saved in the cached object if one searches in the cache for the key (or part of the key). For example

```
cd /var/cache/nginx/test
grep -inr part_of_key *
Binary file 6/29/7bcd0cd0aadfd536cdd7183cd8b77296 matches
```

one can then do

```
strings 6/29/7bcd0cd0aadfd536cdd7183cd8b77296
# content with keys, cached headers and so on
```

The nginx config is (simplified)

```
# part of server1
  location / {
    proxy_pass            http://upstream;
    proxy_cache           zone1;
  }
```

Now I know the directive `proxy_hide_header` and I used trying to remove (and substitute) the headers in the cached object but it doesn't work. It feels like the process is the following:

1. the upstream sends the response
2. nginx reads the response
3. the response is saved in a file in cache
4. operations are performed on the response, like removing headers, to send the response to the client

Therefore there seems no way to affect the headers of the response before this gets saved in cache.

One workaround that I could develop is simply put another nginx server in the middle, so that it could change the headers, that then got saved in the cache in `server1`.

Example

```
# part of server1
  location / 
    proxy_pass            http://upstream-modify-headers;
    proxy_set_header      Host modify.headers;
    proxy_cache           zone1;
  }
```

```
# the upstream
upstream upstream-modify-headers {
  server 127.0.0.1:80;
}
```

```
#the host that modifies the headers
server {
  listen *:80;


  server_name           modify.headers;

      add_header "cache-control" "public, max-age=10, must-revalidate";

  ...

  location / {
    proxy_pass            http://upstream;
    proxy_hide_header     cache-control; #one example header that should be modified in the cache
  }
  ...
  allow 127.0.0.1; #only locally available
}
```

This works, but it requires an additional nginx hosts. **Is it possible instead to override the headers in the cached object within the same nginx server, without adding an additional one in upstream?**

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're looking for `proxy_hide_header` directive.

Comment: I wrote "_Now I know the directive proxy_hide_header and I used trying to remove (and substitute) the headers in the cached object but it doesn't work_"

proxy_hide_header doesn't work, the headers are removed for the response to the client but not for the object in cache.

Comment: Probably because they were cached without `proxy_hide_header` ? Then you can only delete what was cached and recache it with proper header set.

Comment: "Probably because they were cached without proxy_hide_header" what do you mean? My first try was to use `proxy_hide_header` (it is a common discussed directive, thus one tries it early) to remove the header from upstream. I tested it and no matter what, the header from upstream ends in the cache. I even wrote that part where I parsed the cached object (actually many different ones) to see if that worked. I am not sure why you think it works. Maybe do you have a little test setup that you can share?

Comment: I just retested to be sure, it is not happening. `proxy_hide_header`removes the header from the response to the browser, but not from the cached object.

Comment: Then, if it's really so, it looks like a bug in proxy module.

Comment: "Then, if it's really so, it looks like a bug in proxy module." this suggests that you didn't test yourself (or use it previously). It is not great to make a suggestion without really having the experience about the suggestion itself, I think it could be misleading.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably because I'm not on a payroll here. Nginx LLC has a payed support plan, they will definitely provide a tested answers. You should ask there.

Comment: No need to act defensively. I know that stack exchange a community effort, but exactly for that - and especially because many others can read the stuff later - we should strive to provide answers that we test/know about.

No one pays anyone here, but no one forces people to answer either.

My point being: if we answer "randomly" then the trust in the answer gets diluted. Also the reputation that the site gives gets diluted.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, try adding a datestamp on the headers.
You add and then you will be able to differentiate which headers come from the cache and which are new (by comparing in the access log to other timestamps)